# Adding noise to ECG to mimic Electrode Motion Artifacts, Muscle Artifacts, and Baseline Wander in Python

Tags: noise, wavelet

I have clean ECG signals and I want to add noise to them. Specifically, I want the noisy signals to be closest to "real life" type of noise.

Reading [this](https://www.hindawi.com/journals/cmmm/2021/5527904/) paper, I noticed that the researchers distinguished between different type of noise, each from a different artifact. The artifact are Electrode Motion Artifacts (EM), Muscle Artifacts (MA), and Baseline Wander (BW) and a demonstration is given bellow.

How could I mimic those types of noise using Python?

The images that are given below demonstrate the different kinds of noise. Their order is cleaned (Signal), muscle artifact (MA), electrode motion artifact (EM), and baseline wander (BW).

[image: Clean Signal]

[image: Muscle Artifacts (MA)]

[image: Electrode Motion Artifacts (EM)]

[image: Baseline Wander (BW)]